# Using SSRS how do I slide data up if they are null?

Tags: reporting-services, null, slide, slideup

I can't figure out how to slide information up in an SSRS report if the data comes back as NULL. So if I've got an address field with the entire address i want to slide data up (remove white spaces) if data is null.

Comment: What do you mean by slide up the data ? Do you want to remove the `Null` values or the empty values from your report ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I Understood what you are trying to achieve then that is You want to filter out the empty values from the report dataset. 
There are two ways to do that

1) Set condition in your sql so that filtered data will come to the report

2) Filter data in dataset of report

If you have control over the query then always use first approach, But if you dont have control over it then use below method,

For that you can use the report filter [here is more info.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633648.aspx)

For your purpose you can set the filter expression for the dataset as

1) Expression

```
 = IIF( IsNothing(Fields!address.value) || Len(Trim(Fields!address.value)) = 0 ,False,True)
```

2) Set filter Operator `=`

3) Set filter `Value` to `True`

That will filter out the empty data

Comment: Thank you - and you do understand me correctly. The filtered data does come into the report. But all the address fields have to come in however there are times where a part of the data is null/empty. I can't not bring the column in.  So i ave to use the second approach I will test it later today. Thank you.